# Java Login/Registration System

Tags: java

I want to develop a simple login and registration system. The system needs to be able to register a user and allow them to login. Not only this i need to be able to identify who is the current user logged in.

User Class

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class AuctionHouseUsers implements Serializable {

    String userName;
    String password;

    public AuctionHouseUsers(String aUserName, String aPassword)
    {
        this.userName = aUserName;
        this.password = aPassword;
    }
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String aUserName)
    {
        this.userName = aUserName;
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String aPassword)
    {
        this.password = aPassword;
    }
}
```

AuctionHouse Class

```
    public class AuctionHouseManager

ArrayList<AuctionHouseUsers> registeredUsers;
ArrayList<AuctionHouseUsers> logedInUsers;


public AuctionHouseManager()

    logedInUsers = new ArrayList<AuctionHouseUsers>();
    registeredUsers = new ArrayList<AuctionHouseUsers>();
}
    public void registerUser(String username, string password)
    {
        AuctionHouseUsers registeredUser = new AuctionHouseUser(username,password);
        registeredUsers.add(tempUser);
    }
    public void logIn(String username, string password)
    {
      AuctionHouseUsers logedInUser = new AuctionHouseUser(username,password);
      logedInUsers.add(logedInUser);
    }
```

How can i keep track of who (by there username) is currently logged in at this moment in time as i will be designing a gui.

Comment: Which technology are you planning to use...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is not an homework but an actual development project I would advise you to use [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) or [Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) . Both offer support for authentication and access-control (and much more).

Hope this helps.

Comment: first of all before you add the user to the logged user list you should verify that the user credentials match .You can check if the user exist in the registered user list.Then you can check the password and only then add the user to the logged user list.For ease of user you should have methods that retrieve the user object using the username...